# How to align nested items contents

Tags: html, css

I have a layout like [this](https://codepen.io/Kestvir/pen/oNGBWEb) (codepen).

```
.parent {
    display : flex;
    justify-content : space-between;
}

.left {
   flex-grow: 1;
   flex-basis: 0;
  background-color: blue
}

 .right {
   background-color: red;
   flex-grow: 1;
   flex-basis: 0;
}

.center {
  background-color: green;
}

.parent-2 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 30px
}

.parent-3 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 60px
}
```

[image]
Due to margin from the left of the last two items, the items have their contents misaligned in respective of each other in the vertical sense. I would like to align the items so that the green and red parts would align with each other, but the blue should stay misaligned. How would one achieve this?

Edit: I would also like for this to happen automatically for any amount of nested items.

Comment: If the width of red and green is always the same, you can specify the width of these divs and let the blue to calculate automatically.

Comment: Css has first-child and nth-child(2) selectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `flex-basis` with calculation `calc` value

```css
.parent {
    display : flex;
    justify-content : space-between;
}

 .right {
   background-color: red;
   flex: 1 0 0;
}

.center {
  background-color: green;
}

.parent-2 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 30px
}

.parent-3 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 60px
}

.left {
    flex: 0 0 33.33%;
    background-color: blue;
}
.parent.parent-2 .left {
    flex: 0 0 calc(33.33% - 20px);
}
.parent.parent-3 .left {
    flex: 0 0 calc(33.33% - 40px);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left">
    short text.
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    I'm in the center.
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Very loooooooo ooooooooooo oooooooooooooooooo oooooo ooooooooooo ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent parent-2">
  <div class="left">
    short text.
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    I'm in the center.
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Very loooooooo ooooooooooo oooooooooooooooooo oooooo ooooooooooo ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent parent-3">
  <div class="left">
    short text.
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    I'm in the center.
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Very loooooooo ooooooooooo oooooooooooooooooo oooooo ooooooooooo ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just a question, why here: 

parent.parent-2 .left {
    flex: 0 0 calc(33.33% - 20px);
}

we need to subtract 20px instead of 30px, which is the amount of margin-left?